# Strange error in SQL Server Reporting Services, EventID 108

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, skype-for-business

I am using SQL Server 2019 (15.0.1102.861) reporting services. From time to time it fires an error multiple (5-6) times within the same second. There is nothing special that happens at this time, no subscription or any scheduled task or anything else, but of course I can't say if anyone is just opening a report with a - let's say "unoptimal" - query or is trying to edit a report and runs into something. There is no regularity in any way.

In Windows event log it reads:

```
error, ID:108, Source:Report Server (SSRS), Message:Report Server (SSRS)
```

There is no more information, except the word DAX, but I am quite sure that no one uses Data Analysis Expressions (as Analysis Server is not installed, but maybe Skype for Business or Anywhere 365 uses such a thing for the reports and cause this error - could that be the reason?):

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
   <System>
      <Provider Name="Report Server (SSRS)" /> 
      <EventID Qualifiers="0">108</EventID> 
      <Level>2</Level> 
      <Task>2</Task> 
      <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-02-08T06:26:17.553286000Z" /> 
      <EventRecordID>365647</EventRecordID> 
      <Channel>Application</Channel> 
      <Computer>MyReportServer.MyDomain</Computer> 
      <Security /> 
   </System>
   <EventData>
      <Data>Report Server (SSRS)</Data> 
      <Data>DAX</Data> 
   </EventData>
</Event>
```

Just to demonstrate the interval it happens, these are the timestamps for the whole series:

```
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-02-08T06:26:17.553286000Z" /> 
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-02-08T06:26:17.553286000Z" />
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-02-08T06:26:17.537658500Z" />
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-02-08T06:26:17.522032200Z" />
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-02-08T06:26:17.037601300Z" />
```

In the Reporting Service log file I find two warnings during this time, and I don't think they have anything to do with the error above, but just to be complete:

```
2023-02-08 06:26:13.7997|INFO|21|Deleting expired log file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\LogFiles\RSPortal_2023_01_04_19_15_05.log Last written: 04.01.2023 19:15:05
2023-02-08 06:26:13.7997|WARN|21|Exception deleting expired log fileSystem.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\LogFiles\RSPortal_2023_01_04_19_15_05.log' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at Microsoft.BIServer.HostingEnvironment.Logger.DeleteExpiredFilesInternal(Int32 keepUntilDays, FileInfo[] logFiles)
2023-02-08 06:26:23.8306|INFO|21|Deleting expired log file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\LogFiles\RSPortal_2023_01_04_19_15_05.log Last written: 04.01.2023 19:15:05
2023-02-08 06:26:23.8306|WARN|21|Exception deleting expired log fileSystem.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\LogFiles\RSPortal_2023_01_04_19_15_05.log' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at Microsoft.BIServer.HostingEnvironment.Logger.DeleteExpiredFilesInternal(Int32 keepUntilDays, FileInfo[] logFiles)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your log file RSPortal_2023_01_04_19_15_05.log was used by another process. Check other process that might use this file, like the virus scan. If you can reboot the machine, it should solve simply the problem.

Comment: The file is indeed in use, but there's no reason to assume a reboot would fix the issue (whatever is accessing those files will likely continue to do so after a reboot).